# OnLoad method available for UserControl but not for Control

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In WindowsForms.

I have a custom control that contains only one control: a PictureBox.

```
public partial class VarIllumButton : UserControl
```

It uses the OnLoad method:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
    {
        base.OnLoad(e); // Handle the default function
        pictureBox.Image = image0;
    }
```

Since the custom control only has 1 control, I wish to change it to:

```
public partial class VarIllumButton : PictureBox
```

But then I get an error

```
'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a definition for 'OnLoad'
```

Yet, I see that [the Control class does have an OnLoad method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

Can you think of why I can access it from a UserControl, but not from a Control?

Is there another method that I can use that is called when the Control finishes loading?

Comment: This is winforms right?

Comment: I'd suggest you do such initialisation in the constructor and not in the `Load` event.

Comment: image0 is not available at the time the constructor is run. That's why I must use an OnLoad event.

Comment: You are linking the MSDN documentation for the Web UI PictureBox, not the [Winforms one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx)! It has no `OnLoad` method.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an equivalent method that I could use instead of OnLoad?

Comment: Is this question about asp.net/web-forms or windows-forms?

Comment: OK, but your link to the Control.OnLoad method points to the web-forms control.

Comment: @MicroVirus if you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the MSDN documentation with the `OnLoad` mention is for the Web UI controls, not [the WinForms one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox). The WinForms does not have an `OnLoad` method.

The best place would be to assign the image in the constructor, but unfortunately you mention that is not possible. Perhaps you can handle the [`OnCreateControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol)/`CreateControl` event, or you should let the user of the control assign the image at the correct time.

I usually suggest avoiding using the `Load` event of a form/control for doing stuff, because there is an issue with exceptions being swallowed with 32 bits programs on 64 bit windows [[SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a), [article](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)].

Answer (score 0):

(assuming this is an ASP.NET question)

It seems you have an incorrect using directive in your source code, e.g:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Therefore your control is deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, which doesn't have an `OnLoad` method.

Replace that using directive with `using System.Web.UI;`, and it should compile (although there is no `PictureBox` control in `System.Web.UI`).

Comment: "an incorrect using directive"... "using System.Windows.Forms;" .  I wouldn't consider it incorrect. But, yes, you are right, I am using Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

`UserControl` has a load event `protected virtual void OnLoad(EventArgs e)` [`System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.Load`] and as it virtual, it can be overridden as you've done.

But `PictureBox` doen't have any such event, so you can't override. Instead it has a public method load `public void Load()` and event's like `public event AsyncCompletedEventHandler LoadCompleted`, `public event ProgressChangedEventHandler LoadProgressChanged` etc. That's the reason you get the error.

Inheritance hierarchy for `UserControl` UserControl -> ContainerControl -> ScrollableControl -> Control and for `PictureBox` it's  PictureBox -> Control, public void Load() is just a public method in PictureBox class.

Comment: public void Load() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyc6weyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. No, that's for when an _image_ has loaded, not for when the _control_ has loaded. Same for the other ones you mentioned,

Comment: Inheritance hierarchy is something like this UserControl -> ContainerControl -> ScrollableControl -> Control and for  PictureBox it's like PictureBox -> Control, public void Load() is just a public method in PictureBox class. I'm explaining that only.